# Drawing cycles using TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to draw cycles (or polygonal paths) using `TikZ`.  I provide code in which I try to do this using rectangular coordinates and polar coordinates. In the first drawing, I think the cycle is obscured by the help lines.  The second drawing is not drawn the way I had intended.

In both drawings, I have the paths on a grid.  I wanted to make the grid lines a quarter of the thickness of the line segments in the cycles and a light gray.  I think the default thickness of lines drawn by `TikZ` is 0.4pt; so, I thought the specification `line width=0.1pt` would make the help lines a quarter as thick as the cycles.  It did not.  I forgot how to make the lines a light gray. (I thought help lines were gray by default.)

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{intersections,decorations.pathreplacing,positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) grid [xstep=0.5, ystep=0.5, line width=0.1pt,gray] (6,6);
\draw[line width=0.5pt] (4,1) -- ++(1,0) -- ++(0,3) -- ++(-2,0) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\vskip0.25in

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) grid [xstep=0.5, ystep=0.5, line width=0.1pt,gray] (6,6);
\draw[line width=0.5pt] (1,1.5) -- ++(2:135) -- ++(1:135) -- ++(3:90) -- ++ (1:120) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: @PaulGessler Isn't it obvious? The question is: what did I intend to draw and how can I draw it?

Comment: Do you really mean the point at angle 2 degrees and distance 135? Or did you intend e.g. `(135:2)`?

Comment: Use the `line width` as an option of the path (e.g. behind `\draw`), not as an option to `grid`. With the `backgrounds` library, there are additional possibilities to draw a grid *behind* a finished TikZ picture.

Comment: @cfr  I have it switched.  The length of the line segment is 2 and the angle is 135 degrees.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel  I looked at Chapter 2, Section 7 in the manual at the following web site: `http://texample.net/media/pgf/builds/pgfmanualCVS2012-11-04.pdf`.  It said to use `gray,very thin`.  (I think "very thin" is 0.1pt.)  I edited my code, and nothing changed.

Comment: @Adelyn It has to be passed to the path - not the grid, as Qrr. said.

Comment: @cfr  Yep.  I edited it.  (I just have to get a lighter gray, I think.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The options for drawing need to be passed to the `\draw` command rather than `grid`. (EDIT: as [Qrrbrbirlbel said first](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/239338/drawing-cycles-using-tikz/239341#comment568348_239338).)

Polar coordinates are specified as `(angle:distance)`. But note that an angle of `135`, say, is always in the same direction so the first two segments of your path are going in the same direction:

```
(1,1.5) -- ++(135:2) -- ++(135:1)
```

and

```
(1,1.5) -- ++(135:3)
```

are equivalent.

So partially corrected code looks like this:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw [gray, line width=0.1pt] (0,0) grid [xstep=0.5, ystep=0.5] (6,6);
    \draw [line width=0.5pt] (4,1) -- ++(1,0) -- ++(0,3) -- ++(-2,0) -- cycle;
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \vskip0.25in

  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw [gray, line width=0.1pt] (0,0) grid [xstep=0.5, ystep=0.5] (6,6);
    \draw [line width=0.5pt] (1,1.5) -- ++(135:2) -- ++(135:1) -- ++(90:3) -- ++ (120:1) -- cycle;
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

but this is probably not what you want:

[image: not really polygons]

Close up of lines:

[image: close up]

## EDIT

The `shapes.geometric` library lets you draw things like regular polygons easily:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}

  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw [gray, line width=.1pt] (0,0) grid [xstep=0.5, ystep=0.5] (6,6);
    \node [shape=regular polygon, regular polygon sides=5, draw, minimum width=15mm] at (3,3) {};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: regular polygon node]

However, if that doesn't suit, you could try this:

```
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw [gray, line width=.1pt] (0,0) grid [xstep=0.5, ystep=0.5] (6,6);
    \begin{scope}[shift={(1,1.5)}]
      \draw [line width=0.5pt] ++(0:1) -- ++(72:1) -- ++(144:1) -- ++(216:1) -- ++ (288:1) -- cycle;
    \end{scope}
  \end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: regular polygon on grid]

## EDIT EDIT

Or irregular...

```
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw [gray, line width=.1pt] (0,0) grid [xstep=0.5, ystep=0.5] (6,6);
    \begin{scope}[shift={(3,1.5)}]
      \draw [line width=0.5pt] ++(0:2) -- ++(72:1) -- ++(144:3) -- ++(216:2.5) -- ++ (288:.5) -- cycle;
    \end{scope}
  \end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: irregular convex polygon]

Comment: The first graph is what I had intended.  (Are the lines comprising the grid 0.1pt thick?  The quadrilateral does not "stand out.")  For the second drawing, I am looking to make a (convex) pentagon.

Comment: @Adelyn Yes. They are. However, my viewer is very bad at thin lines - either they appear thick or they disappear altogether. (May not be the software's fault - may just be small display.) But, anyway, the pictures I post aren't always reflective of reality.

Comment: @Adelyn See edited answer for close up. Isn't a convex pentagon just a regular one? Why don't you use the `shapes` library?

Comment: @Adelyn See edited answer (again) re. polygons.

Comment: That close-up is convincing.  When printed, I hope the thickness of the lines are in agreement with the  code.

Comment: I was looking to draw a pentagon that is not regular.  I want to illustrate the proposition that the sum of the interior angles of a pentagon is (5-2)180 = 540 degrees.  (I will try to code it myself.)

Comment: @Adelyn See edit. You can create it how you want. I was only illustrating the idea.

Comment: Yes, I see your edited code.  With `shift={(3,1.5)}` and the first coordinate specified as 0 degrees and radius 2, I understand that the vertex of the first point, in rectangular coordinates is (5, 1.5) .  What does the "++" immediately preceding the first coordinate, which is, in this example, (0:2), instruct TikZ to draw?

Comment: @Adelyn Nothing. It just moves there. It doesn't draw anything. But it stays moved there, so to speak. So it moves `2` in the direction given by `0` degrees, starting at the shifted `(0,0)`. `0` degrees is straight across, so `(3,1.5)` + (2,0)` gets `(5,1.5)` as the starting point.